# Java type error - cannot return comparable type from method

Tags: java, types

I'm trying to work with a tree structure for class. In one of the methods, I traverse the tree and return the value of a certain node based on a certain parameter. However, for some reason the Java compiler complains about my return type on this method and I don't understand why it is doing this.

Basically, when I use the following code the program compiles fine:

```
 public class BinNode<E extends Comparable<?super E>> {
    private E value;
    private BinNode left;
    private BinNode right;
    private int size;
    public BinNode(E e) {
        value = e;
        left = right = null;
        size = 1;
    }

    public E example(int k) {
        return value;
    }

    public E getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

But if I change the example method to return the value of the left or right node instead of the current node, I get a compilation error. As in, this code:

```
 public class BinNode<E extends Comparable<?super E>> {
    private E value;
    private BinNode left;
    private BinNode right;
    private int size;
    public BinNode(E e) {
        value = e;
        left = right = null;
        size = 1;
    }

    public E example(int k) {
        return left.getValue();
    }

    public E getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

gives me this error:

```
BinNode.java:13: error: incompatible types: Comparable cannot be converted to E
        return left.getValue();
                            ^
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Comparable<? super E> declared in class BinNode
```

I honestly have no idea why this is happening and would appreciate some insight into what's going on and how I can fix the error.

Comment: You have to use the generic type for your attributes `private BinNode<E> left;` as well. Have a look here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/juneau-generics-2255374.html

Comment: @Philipp That fixed it, that you. I'm not at all familiar with Java and just working off of code someone else gave me.